# How to define a row type that has columns of different tables?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

Normally, I should do something like

```
my_record my_table%ROWTYPE;

cursor c1 (bla bla) is 
select * from my_tables...
```

but what happens if I have something like

```
select b.*, c.col1, c.col2 
from my_table b, mytable1 c ...
```

how can I define one object like `my_record my_table%ROWTYPE` that has exactly the columns I need?

Comment: Is it possible something like my_complex_record my_table%ROWTYPE||mytable1.col1%TYPE||mytable1.col2%TYPE. You got the idea how I want it?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a cursor you just need to declare your variable after the cursor as

```
my_record c1%rowtype;
```

Comment: I just found it myself by looking at Oracle documentation. But Thanks.